# low harm taser using a 9v battery and booster

Tags: step-up

I was trying to build a low harm taser using a 9v battery and boosting it using https://robu.in/product/1000kv-step-up-power-module/?pid=890238 the following booster does to hurt a lot and what would be the case if I use https://www.amazon.in/KitsGuru-400000V-Step-up-High-Voltage-Generator/dp/B071SLYNS9 this one.

Comment: @Justme there are a some use case besides tasers, at my uni we had a device that would electrocute you to actually gives a feel of what it feels like, and to educate about the dangers of electricity. Cattles are held by electrified wires, some games also exists: https://www.amazon.com/Lightning-Reaction-Reloaded-Shocking-Game/dp/B0006B2Q50

Comment: There is no justification for this question.

Comment: @Damien No, if you had been "electrocuted" you would be dead, by definition.

Comment: Define 'low harm'. What harm you want to inflict?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the voltage, it is the current that actually gives the effect of electrocution and the pain.

Thus, it is mostly related to the current output of said device, as long as the voltage is high enough to drive through the body, this is widely dependent of how far are the electrodes.

Note that 10mA causes muscle paralysis 30mA causes lung paralysis and 70mA paralyses the heart, if it is within the current path.

[Source](https://www.elcosh.org/document/1624/888/d000543/section2.html)

Comment: how to make one that cause very low impact like just a tiny effect

Comment: You can look at table of the link of my answer, "1 milliamp = Just a faint tingle". So you can create a high voltage source with a current limitation of 1-2mA.

Comment: @Akash The problem is that something that has a "tiny effect" on one person under certain conditions might cause serious harm to another person under different conditions. Just do not do this.